# PHP not working in production

Tags: php, html, include, responsive-design

I building my 1st responsive & dynamic website.  I tested it locally on WAMP and all my sections show up but when I moved it to my 1and1.com production server my php includes didn't work.  I checked the PHP versions and WAMP and 1and1 are using PHP 5.4.

Can you tell me what I overlooked or did wrong?

The PHP code is:

```
<?php include_once('/includes/Footer.php'); ?>
```

My footer looks like this:

```
    <div id="footer">
    <footer class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 columns">
      <p>Jersey City Dance Academy 107 Westside ave. Jersey City, NJ 07305</p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <ul class="inline-list right">
        <li><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 columns">
      <p>(201) 435-8943    <a    mailto="Info@JerseyCityDanceAcademy.com">Info@JerseyCityDanceAcademy.com</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </footer>
    </div> <!-- end #footer -->
```

**********UPDATE Jan 25th, 2014**********************************
I moved all CSS, JS & includes files so the webpage could find them in the relative path but my includes are still not showing up.  Picture showing file locations in FTP program.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5H94.jpg

Comment: please provide the mentioned php code

Comment: Could you expand a little on "didn't work"?

Comment: Could you also post the entire php code, including the code that includes the footer?

Comment: The pertinent PHP is shown above. The include code is in the 1st section, the file to be included is the 2nd.

Answer (score 2):

additional 1and1 may be Case sensitive  while your WAMP isn't. Check case of your filenames, Footer.php is not footer.php

Comment: Your right.  I was inconsistent in my use of case & fixed this.  Thanks.  I suspect the other issue is the path to the files as everyone else indicated so working on that...

Answer (score 1):

You are using absolute directories for the include command.

```
<?php include_once('/includes/Footer.php'); ?>
```

Absolute directory may be different in your new hosting. You should either check the directory in which the Footer is contained or use relative directories.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not a 100% absolute directory. It is absolute to the root and the root is relative.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php include_once('includes/Footer.php'); ?>`

This will give you a relative path, which your local and live server may read differently.

This assumes that the 'includes' folder is in the same place as index.php

Alternatively (and the recommended method) is to have a path to the root via a variable in front of your includes, like:

`<?php include_once($site_root.'includes/Footer.php'); ?>`

You could even define that as a constant or put all your important data (like root paths) in an array.

Comment: Nope.  There is a live site in the root directory.  The site I'm building will replace it.  So I created a sub directory "New" for the time being: Site/New/ files....
I added all my files and folders to the New folder.  Example the Footer file is located Site/New/Includes/Footer.php

Comment: Your PHP will fail to include if it cannot find it. You must either use the correct relative or absolute path, so either set your path to `Site/New/Includes/Footer.php` for (based on what's provided, and assuming the file you're *including it from* is at the end of the rabbit hole). I really recommend loading php_info and checking the absolute server path and adding it in, because later down the road, it will bite you (and so will mixing cases in pathnames..)

Comment: I moved all CSS, JS & includes files so the webpage could find them in the relative path but my includes are still not showing up. Picture showing file locations in FTP program.